Redeclaration on Foward Ref inside component library using NextJS, Shadcn and pnpm
I am building a component library using shadcn components and NextJS, it runs locally and builds locally without any errors or warnings it publishes with no problem too. When I try to use it on any project it returns this error that somehow I am declaring HTMLProps two times.
Module parse failed: Identifier 'HTMLProps' has already been declared (24:2)
| export const Alert = React.forwardRef<
|   HTMLDivElement,
>   HTMLProps<HTMLDivElement> & VariantProps<typeof alertVariants> & { children: React.ReactNode }
| >(({ className, variant, ...props }, ref) => (
|   <div

This is the only react import in my file:
import React, { HTMLProps } from "react"

Any ideas?
please feel free to ask for more info
I tried to change the import, that was:
import * as React from "react" 

and used like:
export const Alert = React.forwardRef<
  HTMLDivElement,
  React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLDivElement> & VariantProps<typeof alertVariants> & { children: React.ReactNode }
>(({ className, variant, ...props }, ref) => (
  <div
    ref={ref}
    role="alert"
    className={cn(alertVariants({ variant }), className)}
    {...props}
  />
))
Alert.displayName = "Alert"

but it did not work
